# Как связать таблицу с Users определенной группы

Tags: python, django, веб-программирование

вопрос такой:
Существует условный блог на django
У меня есть Сущность Post (Посты с контентом) и мне хотелось бы, чтобы у нее было поле его автора, как мне связать ее с таблицей User, но только состоящих в группе Authors? Или подскажите иной способ реализовать это, если считаете его более оптимальным.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть несколько способов сделать то, что требуется:

1) Используя `Permission`:

Создаём сам `permission`:

```
from myapp.models import BlogPost
from django.contrib.auth.models import Permission
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType

content_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(BlogPost)
permission = Permission.objects.create(
    codename='can_publish',
    name='Can Publish Posts',
    content_type=content_type,
)
```

Даём права пользователю:

```
user.user_permissions.add(permission)
```

Проверяем, есть ли у пользователя права:

```
user.has_perm('myapp.change_blogpost')
```

2) Раз уж вы задали вопрос о Группах, то тогда так:

Создаём группу

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group

group = Group.objects.create(name="Author")
```

Даём права группе

```
group.permissions.add(permission) # берём `permission` из предыдущего примера
```

Добавляем пользователя в группу:

```
user.groups.add(group)
```

Проверяем, включён ли пользователь в группу:

```
if user.groups.filter(name='Author').exists():
    ...
```